# sending a clean pull request, removing ancient commit

Tags: git, github

most of those questions are answered with "use rebase" :) so here is a concrete example so common cases can be better explained.

here is a situation (using letters instead of commit IDs) that I encounter often.

```
upstream/master:
A - B - C - D - E

origin/master:
A - Y - merge B - merge E

origin/feature
A - Y - merge B - merge E - M
```

Now i want to commit the changes made on M while working on origin/feature. but I am still not ready for the changes Y made on master, before i forked the feature.

The changes are easily mergeable as Y and M touch very different files.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you are checked out to origin/feature, and want to get just commit M ready to push to upstream

```
git rebase --onto upstream/master HEAD~1
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you could do:

On origin/feature:

`$ git format-path -1`

This will generate a path of just the M commit.

`$git checkout upstream/master`

`$git am 0001-....`

And you are done. All you are doing is taking the changes you made in M and applying it over upstream/master.
Note: This is more or less similar to the answer of [Andrew C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4021077/andrew-c) but will not land you into any unknown trouble. Git rebase is powerful..but tricky!

Happy Gitting!